# How to determine tuneLength of train function for fitting elastic net

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit elastic net using my data,sorry I can't able to share the data as it's client data. So I wrote following code

```
model <- train(
LnSales_x ~., data = dataReg, method = "glmnet",
trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
tuneLength = 10
)
model$bestTune
coeff=coef(model$finalModel, model$bestTune$lambda)
```

It's giving me coefficient as

```
(Intercept)      12.37486303
 LnPrice_x        .         
 LnPrice_y        .         
 LnPrice_x_comp1  .         
 LnPrice_x_comp2  .         
 LnPrice_x_comp3  0.07760043
 LnPrice_x_comp4 -0.02451433
```

& model$bestTune returns

```
      alpha     lambda
100     1        0.01407534
```

After that I changed tuneLength = 100 then my model$bestTune reurns

```
     alpha     lambda
6264 0.8818182 0.02968187
```

It's giving me coefficient as

```
(Intercept)      12.55749
 LnPrice_x        .      
 LnPrice_y        .      
 LnPrice_x_comp1  .      
 LnPrice_x_comp2  .      
 LnPrice_x_comp3  .      
 LnPrice_x_comp4  .
```

Can you suggest me how should I select tunelength?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using r and caret? Tunelength is just the number of combinations of hyperparameters that the model will use. You should check the metrics (accuracy, mse...) for each of them to select your model.